# Glue with Lambda function calling

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-glue

Can we call Lambda function for each source record in glue script in a loop? and also pass some data from each record?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve it with below snippet

lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda',region_name='us-east-2')
response = lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName='gluelambda')

But I still need to test the looping part and how to pass data(As its not accepting dynamic frame or Data Frame) to it